Definiteness of quadratic form with block matrix structure
Consider the quadratic form:
$$f(x,y) = \sum_{i}c_{i}x_{i}y_{i} + \sum_{ij}(A^{-1})_{ij}x_{i}x_{j} + \sum_{ij}(B^{-1})_{ij}y_{i}y_{j}$$
where $A,B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ are symmetric and positive definite, and $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$. When is $f$ positive definite?
Suppose I have access to $A,B$, but that their inverses $A^{-1},B^{-1}$ are cumbersome to compute. Thus, I would like to be able to answer this question without inverting $A,B$.
Any suggestions on what transformations I can use?

This is only an incomplete answer, to better illustrate the kind of calculation I want to do. Here is a possible transformation one can do:
$$
x=A\xi,\quad
y=B\eta
$$
Then,
$$f = \hat{f}(\xi,\eta) = \xi^{\top}ACB\eta + \frac{1}{2}\xi^{\top}A\xi+\frac{1}{2}\eta^{\top}B\eta$$
Clearly $f(x,y)$ is positive definite if and only if $\hat{f}(\xi,\eta)$ is positive definite. Here we managed to eliminate the inverses of $A,B$.
However this introduces the matrix product $ACB$, which is not even symmetric, so eigenvalue decomposition can be tricky. I'm not sure how to handle it.
